# Error Getting Index Number on Database Using C#, Showing -1

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql

i have made a script in C# to get index number on database using someparameter on ComboBox.

```
private int category(string id) {
        int identity = 0;
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.mysqlconnectionbuilder());
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT kategori.no FROM kategori WHERE kategori.kategori = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            identity = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException msqe)
        {
            Console.Write(msqe.ToString());
        }
        return identity;
    }
```

I want to get Index number based on name example. "Hollywood Movie" --> ID : 2 (in DB)
The result from above script is -1.

How to solve that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ExecuteScalar()` if you want to fetch single value.

```
identity = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

- [**ExecuteScalar** Method (*with example*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: hi @JW thanks for your reply. It's working now. :D cheers and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

**[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)** will returns the **number of rows affected.**

It is used for Insert, Update or Delete. It returns an integer specifying the number of rows affected.

So you need to use **[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)** which returns the **first column of the first row in the result set** returned by the query

*"For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, **the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."*

```
identity = Int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Vishal. Yes, it's using ExecuteScalar and it's working now.