# Error Executing Query on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i have question. I want to store data on my mysqldatabase using this C#

```
private void btnSaveFilm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.mysqlconnectionbuilder());
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO film(judul,genre,asal,kondisi)"
                + "VALUES(@judul,@genre,@asal,@kondisi)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judul", textBoxJudul.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", category(comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asal", asal(comboBoxAsal.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kondisi", checkedStatus());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception exe) 
        { 
            Console.Write("Error on Save Film : " + exe.ToString() + "\n" +exe.Message);
        }

    }
```

but it shows error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error at this line 40:

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre",kategori(comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToString());
```

how to solve that?

Comment: On which line is this exception being thrown?

Comment: @MadSkunk line 40. the script regarding the method is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097646/error-getting-index-number-on-database-using-c-showing-1

Comment: Superb :) Where is the line number 40 in your code ? Add the line number40 in ur code @randytan

Comment: How can we know that which is line 40..??

Comment: @theunlucky this one :  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", kategori(comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToString());

Comment: What are the contents of the category method?

Comment: In which case I would suggest either comboBoxGenre is *null*, or it has no selected value.

Comment: @yumaikas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097646/error-getting-index-number-on-database-using-c-showing-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

refractor your code into this, use `using` statement,

```
string connString = connectionmysqlconnectionbuilder();
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString)
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO film(judul,genre,asal,kondisi) 
                             VALUES(@judul,@genre,@asal,@kondisi)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judul", textBoxJudul.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", kategori(comboBoxGenre.Text).ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asal", asal(comboBoxAsal.Text).ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kondisi", checkedStatus());
        try
        {
            comm.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        (
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        )
    }
}
```

you could also use

```
comboBoxGenre.Text instead of comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue
```

Comment: i just curious why i need to refractor the code? i have another class consist of my mysqlconnectionstringbuilder.

Comment: i'm interested to know about the downvote `:D`, is it because of `AddWithValue`?

Comment: `AddWithValue` performs implicit casting of the datatypes. If I were you, use `Add` instead, see here [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)

Comment: okay, thanks your reply @JW. If i want to make the ComboBox list back to the clear field, i just need to place ComboBox.Text = "" or maybe there is proper way? thanks

Comment: if you are using generic Combobox, and the value of `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`, you need to add empty value first so you can set the value with `ComboBox.Text = ""` but if not then you can just free set it with `ComboBox.Text = ""`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21929/discussion-between-randytan-and-jw)

Answer (score 1):

There can be two reasons:

1.comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue will be null

2.kategori() will be returning null

you can handle null error by using `Convert.ToString()` instead of `variable.toString()`

so use this instead **also for other lines**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", Convert.ToString(kategori(Convert.ToString(comboBoxGenre.SelectedValue))));
```

Comment: I would say that it would be a better practice to not swallow the null case with Convert.ToString(), but instead handle it by either allowing for a null category, or checking for it and taking appropriate action, like maybe throwing an exception.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i just edited the code and change the combobox method for getting the text.